# A year with a question ban

Tags: discussion, post-ban

So last year I got banned from asking questions on SO. This happened when I was cleaning up after my "bad" questions. This was a time I actively started using SO and from time to time I would ask questions which weren't necessarily helpful to others. So I decided to delete those questions. Unknown to me were the consequences. After deleting several questions I received question ban.

I can understand the reason behind it, but I'm not quite sure why this ban is permanent. I improved my questions and undeleted them. I also started giving back by answering other questions. Yet I'm still not able to ask anything on SO.

Why is there such an aggressive ban in place? Wouldn't at least a **single** warning be better? I had no idea such a ban would result from my actions.

Either way, it has been over a year now and I'm wondering what my options are to resurrect my question privileges? From what I've read I have to improve my questions. But you can't polish a turd (unless I'm a mythbuster) and I already did my best on doing so.

Comment: This is different now, and before getting banned users see **lots** of warnings and get rate limited instead i.e. can post only 1 question every day/week/month etc.

Comment: Warnings are in place now, and the q-ban mechanism is to be replaced soon. What is your question here?

Comment: That said, your case does sound quite exceptional, so try emailing the team (or send contact form via "contact us" in the footer) and they might help you.

Comment: @Jan he's obviously appealing the ban and want a "pardon".

Comment: @ShadowWizard no i'm not appealing here. I'm asking what my options are

Comment: @Ortix92 all the options are listed in the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), which I want to believe you've read over and over again. Apart of that, only devine (not a typo ;)) intervention can help, for which you need to request in person - and you just did, and got that intervention.

Answer (score 9):

You were actually very close to the ban threshold - a few more upvoted questions would have gotten you out of it.

Answering more questions - good answers that would gain you reputation would have also helped you (so possibly not as quickly).

I have given you a helping hand - you are out of the question ban. But be careful - it is possible to get back into it (though you *should* get a warning now).

Comment: Thank you very much Oded. I just sent an email to SO, so you could ignore that :) Also, are the questions from other stackexchange sites counting towards threshold?

Comment: @Ortix92 the ban is per-site, other sites are not affected at all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that I know, but since Oded was speaking of more upvoted questions, I was thinking of questions on other sites since I couldn't ask them on SO

Comment: @Ortix92 - I was talking about SO. The question ban currently only looks on the same site - posts on other sites are not taken into consideration.

Comment: The rating system is not clear.  On WebApps I currently have 16 questions.  Of those 16 I have 3 favorites marked, I have 11 question upvotes, only one down vote, and attracted 13 answers.  If a question is badly received from either votes or comments I generally delete it.  Is this not the right thing to do?